# Reverting shifts and rotations to an imported object

Tags: modeling, import, transforms

so essentially I have imported a model fetus to make a mold. At the very beginning, I shifted and rotated the object and the origin of the object to make it easier to manipulate the mold before I developed it. I now need to add to the model which requires importing the brain and editing the mold. However, I need the exact position that the fetus was originally imported to maintain accuracy. Is there any way to recreate the transformations I did on the fetus to the brain, or do revert the changes on the fetus to have the original position it was imported in?

I have tried applying the current modifications from the fetus (seen in figure 3) used to create the mold but I believe since I reset the origin, the changes would not reposition the brain correctly. Eyeballing is not really a solution here unless it is the only one. I need to maintain the accuracy of the relative positions.

[image: position of imported fetus]
Figure 1: imported position of fetus

[image: position of imported brain and fetus]
Figure 2: imported position of fetus and brain

[image: position of fetus used for mold]
Figure 3: Transformed fetus used to develop mold

Comment: If you made changes in edit mode, then i don't think there is a way to do this other than to reimport a fresh copy of the model.

Comment: I have not made any changes to the model in edit mode but I moved and rotated it in object mode. Is there a way to snap the pieces of the mold to the newly imported fetus in the exact way the mold was created?

Answer (score 0):

For reverting, the information you're missing is the exact location of the origin, before it was moved.

If you can find it (maybe reimporting the mesh, and pressing Shift S - cursor to selected) it should be simple to perform a "backflip" (just use negative values for the trasforms)

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and it seems that since I centered the origin on the fetus, and then snapped the fetus to the grid, I can recreate the steps if I was to import the fetus because the origin will be centered on the same place. When I try recreating the shifts on the brain, it does not result in the same transformations since the origin will be snapped differently.

I was thinking that if I could maintain the origin of the imported fetus and somehow snap the fetus to the position of the used for the mold, I could perform those translations to the brain. Is this possible?